# Trying to arrange Ui Responsive to all uwp platform

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to arrange UI Responsive in all uwp platform But some issue arises
,I'm new to uwp development .Any idea how to implement look same in windows 10 mobile ,tabs and desktop.
Xaml code

```
<Grid Name="HomeView" >      

        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Assets/Home/home_android.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mycontrol" Source="/Audio/bg_sound.mp3"  AutoPlay="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" />
        </StackPanel>
        <RelativePanel>
        <Image Source="Assets/Home/btn_learn_colours.png"              
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="20,90,0,60"
               Width="180" Height="200"
               Tapped="L_color_tap"/>
        <Image Source="Assets/Home/btn_paint.png"              
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="220,90,0,0"
               Width="180" Height="200"
               Tapped="Paint"/>
        <Image Source="Assets/Home/btn_quiz_f.png"              
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="440,60,0,0"
               Width="180" Height="200"
               Tapped="Quiz"/>
        <Image Source="Assets/Home/btn_other_apps.png"              
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="440,140,0,0"
               Width="180" Height="200"
               Tapped="Other_Apps"/>
        </RelativePanel>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, this question is pretty broad for the format of this site. However, you should start by never having to set hard set margins and sizes etc on everything and look into AdaptiveTriggers.

Comment: For responsive design, I'd suggest you refer to [Define page layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml) and [Make your app look great on any size screen or window (10 by 10)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/01/make-your-app-look-great-on-any-size-screen-or-window-10-by-10). [Page layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/index#page-layout) also might be helpful.

Comment: Thx chris and Jay. i follow the Link it was helpful but could you suggest me how to adjust image size according to different device .If possible can anyone show me example in refrence to above xaml code